# Adding a polyvinyl alcohol chain onto polyethylene

Tags: polymers, alcohols

For school, my teacher asked what the proper procedure/reaction would be to add a polyvinyl alcohol chain onto a polyethylene chain. Can anyone help? I'll provide additional information if needed.

Comment: Do you want to make a co-polymer? or just a mixture of the 2 polymers? Please give more details.